# Issue when using df_dict2 = pd.read_fwf(io.StringIO(read_data), delim_whitespace=True)

Tags: python, dataframe, whitespace, removing-whitespace, read-fwf

Issue: when loading data frame from string CALLED read_data as follow:

import pandas as pd
import io
read_data = """                      operational               applied  description

---

description                                              Details names
link
statm               working                            The state of the residenat
stats
in-bytes          0 Bytes                            Total number size
in-drops          0                                  Number of student drop
lans
lanst"""

df = pd.read_fwf(io.StringIO(read_data), delim_whitespace=True)

the output as shown in the attached image. The main issue for words "stats" and "lans" the last s got removed when the df created

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: data frame generated using  pd.read_fwf(io.StringIO(read_data), delim_whitespace=True). The output removes the last word from the line with s like "stats" it only gives "stat" as shown in the output  images attached